# Google Apps script- automated email when the checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Hello All,
I would like seek help on below google sheet script which is when the checkbox is checked it cannot auto send email with data column A to E and script i need to add?

```
const wholeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
let sheetName = "name of your sheet";
let activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

function sendEmailWhenBoxIsChecked() {
  let columnIndexOfCheckbox = 6; //column index of where your checkbox is located
  let rowIndexOfCheckbox = 2; //column index of where your checkbox starts
  let activeCellOfActiveSheet = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
  if (
    activeCellOfActiveSheet.getColumn() === columnIndexOfCheckbox
    && activeCellOfActiveSheet.getRowIndex() >= rowIndexOfCheckbox
    && !activeCellOfActiveSheet.isBlank()
  ) {
    let checkbox = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
    if (checkbox.isChecked()) {
      GmailApp.sendEmail("recipient email", "Email header", "Email content or body");
    }

  }

}

function onEdit() {
  let createTrigger = true;
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(trigger => {
    if (trigger.getEventType() === ScriptApp.EventType.ON_EDIT && sendEmailWhenBoxIsChecked.name === trigger.getHandlerFunction()) createTrigger = false;
  });
  if (createTrigger) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(sendEmailWhenBoxIsChecked.name)
      .forSpreadsheet(wholeSheet)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1cYG.png)

Comment: Have you i) put the sheet name on line 2 and ii) set an `onEdit` trigger with `sendEmailWhenBoxIsChecked`?

Comment: Hello, yes i added the script and kindly help to see any script i can add.

Comment: You should be calling `sendEmailwhenBoxIsChecked` _inside_ the `onEdit`. The way you're doing it, you have just set a trigger that doesn't quite work, and your function will only work (send the email) if the checkbox is already checked and you run it again.